# How can I pass my angularjs variable to Php page and retrive it

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, http

I am trying to pass a angularjs variable to a php page using http get but not able to access it in the php page. I want to pass a variable and then perform some calculations on that variable in the php page and then retrive it again in the html page. 
 My code looks like:

## HTML

```
$scope.postFunc = function(){
            $http.post(
                "calculate.php",
                {sal:$scope.sal}
            ).then(function(data){
                alert($scope.sal);
                $http.get("./calculate.php").then(successCall,errorCall);
            });
        }

function successCall(response){

            $scope.total = response.data;
            alert($scope.total);
        }
        function errorCall(response){
            alert("error");
        }
```

#### PHP File

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $salary = $data->sal;
    $da = (20*$salary)/100;
    $ta = (30*$salary)/100;
    $hra = (60*$salary)/100;

    $total_salary = ($salary + $da + $ta + $hra);



    echo json_encode($total_salary);
```

?>

I get an error which says

```
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\php\Grade Task\calculate.php on line 3.
```

Comment: how does $data look like? please put an error_log(print_r($data, true)); in line 3.

Comment: `$data` might be an array. Try `$data[ "sal" ]`.

Comment: @scipper it returns 1.

Comment: @tyb yes it is an array but it shows 0, t i am not able to pass the value from html page to php page and then I want the calculated value back to the html page

Comment: Guys please help. Unable to find any solution

Comment: From the description given its very difficult to poinpoint the problem. What people normally do is POST the value from AngularJS to their server, the server then does the calculation and then responds with the result. So AngularJS makes a POST request and the server responds with the answer after performing the calculation.

Comment: in your angular code you are doing, POST then GET - thats wrong - you do a post and the .then(data) promise resolution contains the answer in the data variable. the server returns the answer as the HTTP response to the POST request.

Comment: @danday74 can you give me a sample code please so I can understand it more clearly. Thanks

Comment: provided an answer with your POST request from Angular to your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$http.post("calculate.php", {sal:$scope.sal}).then(function(answerFromServer){
  console.log(answerFromServer);
});
```

Your server (PHP server?) will need to do the calculation and send the appropriate HTTP response with the answer.

Comment: What should be done if I have to retrive more than one variable from the php page back to the html page?

Comment: you can either send multiple requests or you can send the responses in an array or in a JSON object - God bless you :D

Comment: oh ok got it. Thanks :)